# Jquery Append or Insert Text After Specific Words

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to append word "THIRD" after these two words "FIRST SECOND" but before word "FOURTH".

This appends after "FOURTH":
https://jsfiddle.net/bagn96ee/

```
<p id="para">FIRST SECOND FOURTH</p>
$('#para').append('THIRD');
```

Comment: You can't append, you have to *change*  the text -> https://jsfiddle.net/bagn96ee/1/

Comment: Can you give a little more context on what problem you're trying to solve? There are specific solutions to this exact specific problem with these exact specific pieces of text but I have a feeling you're looking for a more general solution to a more general problem.

Comment: If it's not being added onto the end, it's not being "appended". Adeneo's answer works.

Comment: @dannyid Thanks for comment, I need to insert first image(larger than 200px) url of  page's `<main>` element, IN: `<meta property="og:image" content="HERE"/>` & `pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=some-url&media=HERE` on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't manipulate the text with jQuery. But you extract it with jQuery text() into an string; then manipulate with standard javascript, and finally set it back with jQuery text().

try something like this

```
var words = $('#para').text().split(' ');
words.splice(2,0,'THIRD');
$('#para').text(words.join(' '));
```